# How to authenticate a page automatically in Single Page application

Tags: authentication, iframe, single-page-application, durandal

We are developing a Single Page Application (SPA) using Durandal. I have a view `Test.html`.
This view will be consumed by another application (`App2` which is not SPA) via iFrame. `App2` will access `Test.html` directly via the application url - `http://localhost/App1/#Test`

My question is

- Since we have two separate applications, how do I authenticate the user logged in `App2` and display the view `Test.html` when requested by `App2` via iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

It really does not matter if you are embedding your app2 in an iframe or using it directly. 
What matters is whether you deploy these apps under one domain or different domains.

In case of single domain you don't realy have to do anything on the frontend - just use the authentication cookie from your NOT-SPA app in your SPA app for authenticated requests.

In case of different domains, try implementing oauth implicit grant flow (probably with a [server-side proxy](http://alexbilbie.com/2014/11/oauth-and-javascript/)).